# How does the compiler distinguish nested objects if they have the same address?

Tags: c++, object-model

In the following example (try out [here](http://ideone.com/xCLrLX))

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct a {
    struct b {
        int b1;
    };
    b a1;
    int a2;
};
int main() {
    a test;
    test.a1.b1 = 5;
    test.a2 = 6;

    std::cout<<&test<<" "<<&(test.a1);
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Both the struct and its nestd struct have the same memory location. This makes sense, since the first element to be stored in memory is part of the nested struct.

Proof: 0x7ffd895f86e0 0x7ffd895f86e0

My question is: how does the compiler know what types are stored at this location and is there any overhead from tracking such information at runtime to be expected?

Comment: It knows because you wrote the definition of `struct a` which makes this clear and is understood by the compiler. There is no need for this information at runtime.

Comment: So you're saying that the location of a1 and test are the same - but that's the same as the location of the first member of the struct a being the same location as the struct.  When put like that is it still unexpected?

Comment: The compiler implementation has hard-coded knowledge about how it organises nested structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
struct a {
    int x;
    struct b {
        int b1;
    };
    b a1;
    int a2;
};
```

Do they have the same address? No. Not because they're different, but because "struct" has no binary meaning (before lashing this, keep reading). When your program is compiled, all that matters is the variables inside your structs. The programming language has this superficial thing called "struct" to make things easy for you. But it's not real, unless you do something that requires it to be handled as a one thing (such as copying it), and even then the binary code generated (for run-time) will only represent the elements that are to be copied as a whole, not the "struct", per se.

When you instantiate `a` there, this is how it looks like in memory:

```
int x - int b1 - int a2
```

It's blocks in memory with ints. It's not structs.

You can verify this using pointers. In your code:

```
*(int*)(&test) //is b1
*((int*)(&test)+1) //is a2
```

So you see there's only two ints in memory that matter.

PS: Notice that all this assumes that we're not dealing with polymorphism, which adds more memory blocks that represent the vtable. That's a story for another day.

Comment: This description works reasonably well for standard-layout classes on sensible platforms with no optimizations turned on, but breaks apart quickly with virtual functions and virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Quentin With virtual stuff, this breaks, absolutely, which is why binary interfacing is done with C, not C++. But that's very deep, I assume. I'm gonna add more info about that.

Answer (score 1):

Forget for a moment that you're dealing with structs. How does the compiler know that a particular memory location holds an `int` or a `float`? In one sense, it doesn't. But **within a program**, variables have a **type** and that **type** tells the compiler what operations are valid on that variable. It doesn't matter what the address of the object is; what matters is what type the program says it is. So:

```
int i = 3;
i = i + 1;
```

The compiler knows how to do that addition because the program said to treat the memory location named `i` as an `int` value.

```
float f = 4.0;
f = f + 1;
```

The compiler knows how to do that addition because the program said to treat the memory location named `f` as a `float` value.

In your example, `test.a1.b1` has type `int` because the program said so. And `test.a1` has type a::b`because the program said so. And`test`has type`a` because the program said so.

Answer (score 0):

Lets "draw" how the structure looks in memory (together with the "pointers" to it):

```
+----+----+
| a1 | a2 |
+----+----+
^    ^
|    |
|    &test.a2
|
&test
|
&test.a1
```

That should hopefully make it quite clear how two different structures can occupy the same memory.

It should be noted that this is only for structures with non-virtual functions. Virtual functions may cause other hidden members to be included in the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is you who explicitly tells the compiler what type is stored at a given location by writing expressions such as &test and &(test.a1).